# How to prevent http packet capture in exoPlayer Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer, certificate-pinning

I am using the `exoplayer` library in an android app to play video hosted on a server as https://ok.ru/video .
I found that anyone can get and download video easily.

If I use a token and send as header, it can be captured by the 'Packet Capture' app.

Is there any way to prevent such data leaks.

did i can use `Certificate pinning` with exoPlayer?

please help me

Comment: Your best solution is some commercial DRM solution. I doubt anyone will help you with that in here. Otherwise, the 'they can download it' problem will never be solved, and even then its a question of time.

Comment: The simple answer is that you cannot.  Packet capture operates on a network interface layer, so your app doesn' know about its existence in the first place.